# Shrinking NTFS partition: numerical result out of range error

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I have a NTFS partition on my 2TB hard disk. Currently it is 1.7TB big, and there's some unallocated space to the right of it of about 100GB. There are no other partitions on the disk.

I would like to shrink the NTFS partition so that I have more unallocated space to create other partitions. However, when I shrink the NTFS partition to any size smaller than what it is, I get an error in GParted. I am doing this from a linux live cd.

This is the error:
http://pastebin.com/FvKdFi05

Could somebody help me with what's going on?